# Javascript: Passing variable into ShopifyApp initialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I'm building a we app which uses the [Shopify Embedded App SDK](http://docs.shopify.com/embedded-app-sdk). I'm trying to extract a param from the request url, and passing this into a javascript initialize function for the embedded app. However the captured variable doesn't insert as expected.

I can successfully capture the params from the request, however the variable never outputs within the initialize function.

Here's my code so far:

```
<script src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/assets/external/app.js?123445566"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//Capture the params from the URL = Works fine
var urlParams;
(window.onpopstate = function () {
    var match,
        pl     = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
        search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
        decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); },
        query  = window.location.search.substring(1);

    urlParams = {};
    while (match = search.exec(query))
       urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
})();

//This is the part I am having troubles with, the urlParams["shop"] just outputs "urlParams["shop"]" instead of the value
ShopifyApp.init({
    apiKey: "thiscontainsthecorrectapikeyvalue",  // Expects: 32 character API key string like ff9b1d04414785029e066f8fd0465d00
    shopOrigin: 'https://' + urlParams["shop"],  // Expects: https://exampleshop.myshopify.com
    debug: true
  });

//This alert works as expected, and shows the correct value: "exampleshop.myshopify.com"
alert(urlParams["shop"]);
</script>
```

I can use plain javascript or jquery, but please note I am noob to both, mainly familiar with rails (which I cannot use in this particular page).

Any ideas on how to pass the captured param into the initialize function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure but can be the problem of asynchronous concept, use the `urlParams` after made it.

```
(window.onpopstate = function () {
      ......
      ......
      urlParams = {};
      while (match = search.exec(query)){
          urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
      }

      callInit(urlParams); //use when it is made
})();

function callInit(urlParams){
    ShopifyApp.init({
        apiKey: "thiscontainsthecorrectapikeyvalue", //API Key
        shopOrigin: 'https://' + urlParams["shop"],
        debug: true
      });

}
```

Comment: Why would you do this anyway? If your App code is running client-side in a shop, you know from the server-side response the shop. So you don't parse that from the URL, you simply get that from your session. 

Be curious to know why you're doing your pattern like that...

Comment: Yeah, I'll admit it does seem a bit backwards... I need to know the shopify shop of the shopifyshop that is visiting my shopifyshop ;) You'll see eventually.. all the best.